# ApplescriptObjC Image Well

Tags: objective-c, image, applescript

I got a "Image Well" that i try to fill via Applescript in a ApplescriptObjC.

My Code looks like

```
script AppDelegate
    property parent : class "NSObject"
    property myImageView : missing value
    set myImage to NSImage's alloc()'s initWithContentsOfFile_("/Users/xxx/Desktop/red.png")
    myImageView's setImage_(myImage)
end script
```

But the image never shown in the "myImageView" Image Well (they are linked in the xib File).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a slight syntax modification to this line:

```
set myImage to current application's NSImage's alloc's initWithContentsOfFile_("/Users/xxx/Desktop/red.png")
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Sometimes it's a real bear getting just the right syntax.